# How do I refresh components placed in a GridLayout with the array it was based on?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I am creating what is pretty much an excel spreadsheet based on JTextFields in a GridLayout. I want to be able to type something into a cell, press enter, and have the cell be set to the appropriate subclass based on the input String.

The only subclass of Cell I have working at the moment is DateCell. I can successfully set the subclass in the correct place in the 2d Cell array; however, this does not show in the GUI, and my current refresh method does not work. I would like it to update the JFrame to display the new text in the JTextFields.

Any suggestions on why the refresh method does not work, how the refresh method could work, or a way to do the program without the refresh method would be deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the GUI class:

```
package spreadsheet;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import cell.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public  static final int ASCII_SHIFT = 64;

    private JTextField[][] grid;
    private Cell[][] sheet;

    public GUI(int height, char letter) {

        //sets the title to "TextExcel"
        super("TextExcel");

        //creates multidimensional Cell array
        sheet = new Cell[height][letter - ASCII_SHIFT + 1];

        //creates an array of text fields
        grid = new JTextField[sheet.length + 1][sheet[0].length];

        //creates a grid layout
        setLayout(new GridLayout(grid.length, grid[0].length));

        //create event handler
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        //makes the corner box blank
        grid[0][0] = new JTextField();
        grid[0][0].setEditable(false);

        //numbers the rows
        for (int i = 1; i < grid.length; i++) {
            grid[i][0] = new JTextField(Integer.toString(i));
            grid[i][0].setEditable(false);
        }

        //letters the columns
        for (int j = 1; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
            byte[] character = {(byte) (j + ASCII_SHIFT)};
            grid[0][j] = new JTextField(new String(character));
            grid[0][j].setEditable(false);
        }

        //initializes the cells
        for (int row = 1; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col < grid[0].length; col++) {
                if (sheet[row-1][col-1] == null) {
                    grid[row][col] = new JTextField();
                } else {
                grid[row][col] = new JTextField(sheet[row-1][col-1].toString());
                }
                grid[row][col].addActionListener(handler);
            }
        }

        //adds the boxes to the GUI
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
                grid[i][j].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                add(grid[i][j]);
            }
        }           
    }

    public GUI() {
        this(10, 'G');
    }

    //will eventually return proper subclass
    public Cell parse(String s) {
        Cell output = new DateCell(s);
        return output;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        for (int row = 1; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col < grid[0].length; col++) {
                if (sheet[row - 1][col - 1] != null && !grid[row][col].getText().equals(sheet[row - 1][col - 1].toString())) {
                    grid[row][col] = new JTextField(sheet[row - 1][col - 1].toString());
                    System.out.println(sheet[row - 1][col - 1].toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class Handler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int row = 1; row < grid.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 1; col < grid[0].length; col++) {
                    if (grid[row][col] == e.getSource()) {
                        sheet[row - 1][col - 1] = parse(e.getActionCommand());
                        refresh();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the client code:

```
package client;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import spreadsheet.GUI;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(1000, 618);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The Cell class is just this:

```
package cell;

abstract public class Cell {

}
```

And the DateCell class:

```
package cell;

public class DateCell extends Cell{

    private int month, day, year;
    public static final String[] MONTH = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
            "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

    public DateCell(int month, int day, int year) {
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public DateCell(String s) {
        int firstSlash = s.indexOf('/');
        int secondSlash = s.lastIndexOf('/');
        month = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, firstSlash));
        day = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(firstSlash + 1, secondSlash));
        if (s.substring(secondSlash + 1).length() < 4) {
            year = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(secondSlash + 1)) + 2000;
        } else {
            year = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(secondSlash + 1));
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return MONTH[month-1] + " " + day + ", " + year;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a JTable for something like this and work with the renderers for each column. But if you need to continue with what you have and need our help, you will likely need to post more code, enough so that your code compiles and runs for us, but not so much as to overwhelm us with code.

Comment: @willw12 `and my current refresh method does not work` So can you describe what your `refresh()` method is supposed to do?